# Rust compare Option<Vec<u8>> with Option<&[u8]>

Tags: rust

Is there an elegant way to compare `Option<Vec<u8>>` for equality with `Option<&[u8]>`? (Or equivalently with `Result` instead of `Option`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to convert `Option<Vec<u8>>` to `Option<&[u8]>`, using [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) and `Index` trait:

```rust
fn foo(a: Option<Vec<u8>>, b: Option<&[u8]>) -> bool {
    a.as_ref().map(|x| &x[..]) == b
}
```

As of Rust 1.40, you can use [`as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref):

```rust
fn foo(a: Option<Vec<u8>>, b: Option<&[u8]>) -> bool {
    a.as_deref() == b
}
```

Comment: You were just a bit faster, ok :)

Comment: @Cerberus I don't mind, your answer use `Vec::as_ref` mine not, proven again there is not one and only one style in Rust ;)

Comment: Yeat another option would be `&**x`.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it's suboptimal, but this code seems to compile:

```
fn cmp(first: Option<Vec<u8>>, second: Option<&[u8]>) -> bool {
    first.as_ref().map(Vec::as_ref) == second
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbba72592a0635ee2369436ed2a66419)

There are two key transformations here:

1. The first Option holds the owned value, the second - a reference. So we should go from `Option<T>` (or `&Option<T>`) to `Option<&T>`, and this is achieved using the [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) method of `Option`.
2. The first `Option` now holds `&Vec<u8>`, and we're going to compare it to `&[u8]`. This is handled again by the [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-AsRef%3C%5BT%5D%3E) method, now defined on the `AsRef<[u8]>` trait and implemented on `Vec`.

Comment: Ah so could I equivalently do `first.map(Vec::as_slice) == second`?

Comment: You will need the first `as_ref()` anyway - I've just checked, it will not compile otherwise. But yes, `Vec::as_ref` and `Vec::as_slice` seem to be interchangable here.

Comment: What language is this?  Tag it.

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong? The question is tagged (and if it wasn't, you'd ask the asker, not me).